# Eigenvector of a complete graph Laplacian

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

Can somebody help me prove why $v=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \dots 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ is the eigenvector of every complete graph Laplacian matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an eigenvector of any graph Laplacian, because the entries of $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$ are the row sums, which are all zero in a graph Laplacian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the definition of a graph Laplacian is $L=D-A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix.

Now $Lv$ is a vector whose $i^\text{th}$ component is the sum of entries in the $i^\text{th}$ row in $L$. But the sum of entries in the $i^\text{th}$ row of $D$ is $\deg(v_i)$ by definition, as is the sum of entries of the $i^\text{th}$ row of $A$, because this counts all vertices that $v_i$ is adjacent to, (with multiplicity of edges if the graph is not simple).

So these cancel out, leaving $0$, and hence $Av = 0v$.